# apache forward proxy - how to override a destination address?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, rewrite, mod-proxy

I'm running apache as a forward proxy to do header injection, URL manipulation, and request logging for some Android apps and I'd need to override the destination for some requests.

For example, `www.example.com` would have an IP address of `1.2.3.4` but I need to divert the traffic to `4.3.2.1` without changing the application or affecting any other apps running on the apache server.

I'd also need the flexibility to override the address under different conditions, which means that manipulating `/etc/hosts` is not an option.

The clients are apps running on Android emulators which are configured to use apache proxy instances running on the host machine.

So far I have a setup like this:

```
## conf.d/proxy_a.conf
## proxy_b.conf, proxy_c.conf listen on different ports with different mappings / headers

Listen localhost:16002

<VirtualHost localhost:16002>
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        RewriteEngine On

        <Proxy "http://www.example.com/*">
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from localhost

                RequestHeader set host "www.example.com"
                RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://4.3.2.1/$1 [NE]
        </Proxy>

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from localhost
        </Proxy>

        ## also tried, doesn't work
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://4.3.2.1/$1 [NE]

        RequestHeader set x-custom-header "abcdefgh"

        RequestHeader merge user-agent "proxy16002"

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm aware that the functionality I'm looking for is easily achievable with a reverse proxy, but I'm looking for a solution using a straight proxy (no need to modify `/etc/hosts` or applications).

What's missing? Is this even possible with apache (2.2)?

Comment: Did my answer http://serverfault.com/a/716792/101203 solve your question?  If so, I'd appreciate if you upvote and/or mark it as accepted so I get credit and also so people in the future who read this know that it was a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're wanting, but you could set up another Apache proxy such as in a virtual machine and modify the /etc/hosts file there.  Then traffic would travel through two proxies - the one you have now followed by the one you set up on the virtual machine.  Not ideal I know, but a possible solution if nobody comes up with something better.

Alternately you could modify Apache source and recompile it, but that's not ideal either.